# How to make a dynamic dropdown with Ajax in Vue.js

Tags: ajax, vue.js

I'm newbie to Vue.js. I've been stock in making a dynamic dropdown with Ajax in Vue.js. I have no idea how to populate the select tag with data from the API that is hosted in [Google App Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) (GAE) and made in [Flask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flask_%28web_framework%29).

#### File *index.html*

```
<div id="app2">
    <select v-model="table_list">
        <option v-for="item in table_list" :value="item">{{ item }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: {
    table_list: []
  },
  created: function () {
    var tableList = this.tableList
    axios.get('API_URL').then(function (response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
        tableList.push(response.data[i])
      }
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('failure')
    })
  }
```

The data of the API:

```
["test","test1","test2","test3"]
```

#### File *flask.py*

```
from flask import Flask, request
from google.cloud import bigquery
from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def tables_list():
    client = bigquery.Client()
    dataset_id = 'test_table'
    tables = client.list_tables(dataset_id)  # Make an API request.
    tables_list = [];

    for table in tables:
        tables_list.append(table.table_id)
    return jsonify(tables_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model="table_list"` should be a selected model, not the list itself.

```
<select v-model="table_list_selected">
   <option v-for="item in table_list">{{ item }}</option>
</select>
```

And `data:` should return a function, plus the model name is `table_list`, not `tableList`

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app2',
  data: () => ({
    table_list: [],
    table_list_selected: ''
  }),
```

Also, when you want to keep the scope of `this` when calling a function, either use arrow functions, or bind `this` to the function or do away with the callback and use async/await.

```
created: function () {
    axios.get('API_URL').then(response => {
      this.table_list = response.data
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('failure')
    })
}
```

Or with bind()

```
created: function () {
    axios.get('API_URL').then(function(response) {
      this.table_list = response.data
    }.bind(this)).catch(function (error) {
      console.log('failure')
    })
}
```

Or with async/await

```
created: async function () {
    try {
       this.table_list = await axios.get('API_URL').data
    } catch (e) {
       console.log('failure')
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your beautiful code . I tried all of them but option tag seems to be blank . Is there any prom in the format of api data ?? and I added API source coed (flask.py) for your reference

Comment: look in browser console network tab for the structure, make sure you fixed the typo and debug `this.table_list`, without seeing your complete code as it is when it's not working, cant tell specifically what the issue is

Comment: I debug in chrome developer console and I found out this prom is caused by CORS policy . thank you for your great advice

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using an existing flexible solution for selects/dropdowns with built-in support of dynamic contents.

E.g. *[Vue-Multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org)*.

Comment: I debug in chrome developer console and I found out this prom is caused by CORS policy . thank you for your great advice

Comment: [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) = Cross-origin resource sharing